# Как сменить стиль кнопки при смене фокуса?

Tags: css

Мне необходимо изменить стиль кнопки при нажатии (удержании) и переводом фокуса на другой элемент. Предположим, имеются 2 кнопки, нажимаю на одну и задерживаю и перевожу фокус на другой элемент путем нажатия на <kbd>Tab</kbd>, стиль первой кнопки доложен измениться.

Пытался сделать путем `button:active:not(:focus)`. Но стиль меняется только тогда, когда меняется фокус у самого окна, с помощью <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом CSS такой возможности нет. Элементы на странице не имеют фокуса при загрузке (если не указан`autofocus` конечно). Следовательно, все они подходят под правило `:not(:focus)`.

Как вариант, можно средствами `jquery` стилизовать элемент, с которого "ушёл" фокус, таким образом:

```js
$("button").focusout(function() {  
    $('.lastFocus').toggleClass('lastFocus');    
    $(this).toggleClass('lastFocus');
 })
```

```css
button:focus {
  color: blue;
}
.lastFocus {
    color: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Кнопка</button>
<button>Кнопка</button>
<button>Кнопка</button>
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: мне необходимо средствами css